# jQuery EasySlider 1.7, customized button doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, easyslider

So I'm kind of new to jQuery, but I can't see why the "Next" button doesn't work. The "Previous" button works just fine.

[Test](http://semiconia.com/test/)

You cannot see the previous button here because there's no previous slide, but I have tried with enabling the text option and going to the next slide and it works just fine.

I'm applying the same code to the "next" button, but it just doesn't work. Any idea?

- It's a vertical slide. Click on the little arrow.

Here is the part which doesn't seem to work the way it's supposed to.

```
<span id="nextBtn"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('down','','_img/downover.png',1)"><img src="_img/down.png" alt="Browse Down" name="down" width="53" height="35" hspace="130" border="0"></a></span>
```

This is odd, because the same lines of code for transition to the previous slide works perfectly:

```
<span id="prevBtn"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('up','','_img/upover.png',1)"><img src="_img/up.png" alt="Browse Up" hspace="130" name="up" width="53" height="35" border="0"></a></span>
```

Comment: Why dont you paste the code here?

Comment: There is already a link showing the code in action. Click on it and see the source code. :)

Comment: It is always helpful to post the code if possible. Strip it down if necessary, but your code may not remain at the link you've provided, so in a month this question may become useless.

Comment: Here. I added the codes, but I think you need to go through the source codes completely to understand where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ATTENTION: If anybody still has problem with multiple sliders in vertical mode, just use the 1.5 release. 1.7 seems to have a bug which prevents the buttons from working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have duplicated buttons, because the script automatically adds "previous" and "next" spans with the desired id.

Try removing your prev/next tags and let the script creating it, or set `controlsShow: False`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but still it doesn't work. It could have something to do with duplication. The first one works no matter if it is called as a "next" or as a "previous", but the second one doesn't.

Comment: Found it. It seems the script somehow conflicts with the iFrame. I created two separate classes and put one of the arrows in each. For some unknown reason the codes should come before the slider div or else it won't work. And there you have it: www.semiconia.com/test

Comment: I just noticed that it has some font and positioning problems on all browsers, but chrome. Darn it! :| Anyway, this has nothing to do with the script. I have to modify the CSS.